# getting items by eid from datomic, too few inputs?

Tags: clojure, datomic

So I'm trying to use the entity id to retrieve items recently transacted to the datomic database.

However, when invoking (get-post-by-eid zzzzzzzzz) I get an error

```
IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo :db.error/too-few-inputs Query expected 2 inputs but received 1  datomic.error/arg (error.clj:57)


(defn get-post-by-eid [eid]
   (d/q '[:find ?title ?content ?tags ?eid
              :in $ ?eid
              :where
              [?eid post/title ?title]
              [?eid post/content ?content]
              [?eid post/tag ?tags]] (d/db conn)))
```

So I figure my query string must be malformed..

I've been looking at http://www.learndatalogtoday.org/chapter/3 but still not sure where I'm going astray.

Any help is appreciated (=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `:in` clause specifies that you're expecting two data sources to be passed to the `q` function. `$ ?eid` means that you're saying you're going to pass in a database (bound to `$`), and some other value, which will be bound to `?eid`.

Like this:

```
(defn get-post-by-eid [eid]                  
  (d/q '[:find ?title ?content ?tags ?eid    
         :in $ ?eid                          
         :where                              
         [?eid post/title ?title]            
         [?eid post/content ?content]        
         [?eid post/tag ?tags]]              
       (d/db conn)                           
       eid))
```

Otherwise, there's no way for your `eid` parameter to actually get "into" the query. You have to pass it explicitly, there's no magic there.

Comment: oh wow!  So anything that goes into the :in clause must also explicitly be added into the (d/q  ...   ) at the end.  That makes a lot of sense now since (d/q '[find clause] (d/db conn) eid) is just like passing arguments to any other operator.  Thanks for that very clear answer.  Figured I'd elaborate since maybe someone will have a similar question in the future (= thanks for your clear answer

Comment: Exactly. Bindings in the `:in` clause map one-to-one with arguments to `q`